# Is there any possibility to find a section of code in that file is?

Tags: html, web-inspector

Often when I inspect the HTML code of a site have difficulty in finding out what file is part of a specific DIV.

For example if you inspect a CMS that has many files and modules I can not tell exactly where it is that div or a script JS.

If we inspect the site to find a JS code but do not know where it belongs.
Look at the picture below

http://i60.tinypic.com/2njln9f.jpg

I hope you have understood what I mean.
If it's not clear I will return with more information

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most often it's being parsed by a template parser (i.e. using `PHP`) and you can't exactly find out where a specific line comes from. This requires knowledge of the CMS / module and its template system.

Comment: Since the browser only receives the combined HTML output without any traces of what files they came from: no.

Comment: From web-inspector, no it is not possible. You need to examine the CMS itself and see how the final HTML is produced.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,

From web-inspector, it is not possible.

Because the browser only receives the combined `html` output.

But, You will be able to see all the javascript functions which have executed due to your actions. You can view them one by one to figure out which method has caused the mischief.